# Getting SublimeText to run from terminal in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext3

I am trying to get the `subl` command work for Sublime Text 3 in the terminal.The problem I currently have is when I

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

It returns

```
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: File exists
```

Comment: do you already have Sublime Text 2 installed, and linked to the `subl` command?

Comment: Yes I do.I have Un-Installed sublime text 2 already thou.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you already have Sublime Text 2 installed and have linked `/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` to `/usr/local/bin/subl`, you'll just need to change the name of the link for ST3. Try

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl3
```

instead.

---

If you don't want to have both versions installed, type `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl` then try creating the symlink to ST3 again.

Comment: @MattDMo---  Permission denied.

Comment: I still have the original problem file exists this time ,it is ln: /usr/local/bin/subl3: File exists

Comment: Did you run `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl` first, then the `ln -s ...` statement?

Comment: ..Yes I did.The only problem I have now is that the subl command does not work.

Comment: What happens if you type `/usr/local/bin/subl`?

Comment: it says no such file or directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33723/discussion-between-mattdmo-and-user1850254)